# Finegrained Field Permissions

Tags: users, organic-groups

I'm currently creating a calendar where the events are Group Content. The calendar now shows only the events from the groups of which you are a member - unless the event is public.
I would however like to be able to let everyone see the titles of every event - independantly of the groups - every other field should be hidden.
This is achieved through the OG field permissions - however this doesn't allow the users to create public event anymore because the fields are hidden from every event.

To sum the problem up - I would like to:

Let the users create an event - and determin if it should be private or public
If the event is private - only the title is shown to non-members
If the event is public - everthing is shown to non-members
How am I able to achieve this?